# Método POST Web API retornando null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, post

Estou fazendo uma Web API em C# ASP.NET e no método POST o valor está me retornando `null`.

Estou usando o Postman para jogar um JSON dentro de valor mas ainda me retorna `null`.

```
public string Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    return value;
}
```

No Postman estou fazendo o seguinte

```
{
    "value" : "ana"
}
```

Comment: Na assinatura do método está esperando receber e retornar uma string, e você está enviando um objeto, pode ser isso. Reproduzi no .Net Core aqui e o Kestrel nem aceita a requisição. Você pode usar ```dynamic``` para aceitar objetos com estrutura indefinida, mas recomendo apenas para fins de estudo ou casos muito específicos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Postman você deve enviar uma *string* e não um objeto.

Ou seja, o payload deve ser:

```
"ana"
```